# R function: "Object not found" in function created from working code

Tags: r

*edit: This question has been answered, I have been able to make it work with the solution provided by Jilber Urbina. get(X) changes the axis labelling which can be reverted with `ggplot( ... + labs (x= X, y = Y)`. I appreciate the help.*

I want to create a simple function for exploring a data set visually ("data"). The data set contains among others two variables: "type" is a factor and "weight" is numeric. Here is the working code that I started with:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
 ggplot(aes(type, weight)) +
 geom_boxplot()
```

This creates the boxplots that I want. Now, if I make a function and use it I get an error message:

```
data_box <- function(X,Y) {
 data %>%
 ggplot(aes(X, Y)) + 
 geom_boxplot()
 }

data_box(type, weight)
```

> Error in check_factor(.f) : object 'type' not found

I would much appreciate your help in creating a function that does what the code does.

Comment: Referencing data not explicitly defined within or passed to a function is poor form, rendering the work unreproducible, difficult to troubleshoot, and prone to many other problems. For example, you use `data` in the function but never define it or pass it. I suggest you provide a `data=` argument in your function declaration. Further, your call to `data_box` is passing an object named `type` which is not defined, perhaps you mean to be using non-standard evaluation? That's a bit more complex, https://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @r2evans comment, you can add a third argument `data` and use `get()` for searching by name, so you can give variables names inside quotation marks:

```
data_box <- function(X,Y, data) {
  data %>%
    ggplot(aes(get(X), get(Y))) + 
    geom_boxplot()
}

data_box("Subject", "time", Indometh)
```

Comment: Yeah, but X and Y are columns of the data frame that he/she is also passing.  So redundant. He/she only needs to pass the data frame and then refer to the columns in his function.  i.e., `data$X, data$Y`

Comment: `get(X)` works, `data$X` gives an error:

>>Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (80): x, y
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'X'. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'Y'. 
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'X'. 
4: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'Y'. 

`get(X)` however rewrites the axis name as "get(X)"<<

I have relented from creating a function for this problem, because it is significantly more complex than I imagined.